# Emacs: load package only for given major mode in init.el

Tags: emacs, elisp

I made some time ago a .el file (epx.el) for some files with a specific format that I am using. I load it in my init.el through `(require 'epx)`.

The problem is that in this epx.el, there is:

```
(defadvice comment-region (after indent-after activate)
  (indent-region beg end)
  )
(defadvice uncomment-region (after indent-after activate)
  (indent-region beg end)
  )
```

I got trouble because it affects the behavior of the comment functions (such as `comment-dwim`) in other major modes (in particular in the python mode: when I uncomment a commented region, it breaks my indentation...). If I comment these lines in epx.el, there is no more problems.

So how could these `(defadvice ...)` only have effect in the epx major mode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the major mode of the current buffer, and take action only if it's `exp-mode`:

```
(defadvice comment-region (after indent-after activate)
  (if (derived-mode-p 'exp-mode)
      (indent-region beg end))
  )
(defadvice uncomment-region (after indent-after activate)
  (if (derived-mode-p 'exp-mode)
      (indent-region beg end))
  )
```

EDIT: use `derived-mode-p` as suggested by @Stefan.

Comment: `(buffer-local-value 'major-mode (current-buffer))` is a round-about way to write `major-mode`.  And usually to test the major mode, I recommend `derived-mode-p`.

Comment: Thanks, I've modified the answer to use your suggestion.